# JDBC as400 library list parameter not working?

Tags: jdbc, ibm-midrange

I have a JDBC connection string to an as400:

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:as400://hostname/;libraries=LIB1,LIB2,LIB3";
```

My understanding from these docs:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=properties-jdbc-librarylist-property

Is that if a table cannot be found in LIB1 then LIB2 will be search, followed by LIB3 etc.

Here from the docs:

3. Default SQL schema not specified on URL and "libraries" property is specified

***No default SQL schema. All libraries specified in property are searched.***

BUT when I execute code that looks for a table that I know doesn't exists in LIB1 but does exist in LIB2 the code falls over saying that it's can't find the table in LIB1. My expectation is that it should have traversed the library list and found the table in LIB2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
;naming=system
```

Fixed it so closing question